# Ionic - cordova version error in initialization Windows 7 (Cordova is updated,admin mode)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to get started with Ionic. I followed the instructions on the quick start and entered the following commands: (http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

```
npm -g install cordova ionic
ionic start Notebook blank
```

The tool is not able to create the project and stops with the following error message:

```
E:\Personal\projects>ionic start Notebook blank
Creating Ionic app in folder E:\Personal\projects\Notebook based on blank project

Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s

Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-blank/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s

Update config.xml
Initializing cordova project
Unable to add plugins. Perhaps your version of Cordova is too old. Try updating
(npm install -g cordova), removing this project folder, and trying again. (CLI v 1.3.16)
```

I have installed both cordova and ionic over again and am running in administrative mode.

I notice that the config.xml remains blank. Is that a problem?

This question is similar to: [Cordova version error while using ionic to create new app although cordova is latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982982/cordova-version-error-while-using-ionic-to-create-new-app-although-cordova-is-la)

But I was unable to resolve it with admin mode. And I am not even getting an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error two weeks ago. Solution for me was to remove the Android SDK and afterwards a clean install of it.

After that i also did a `npm install -g cordova ionic` to be sure the SDK is linked correct.

Comment: Basically clean installing everything solved the issue.